# find_packages doesn't find my Python file

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a directory tree like this:

```
dir/
    A/
        __init__.py
        something.py
```

I used `find_packages` on `dir/A` and expected it to find `something.py`. However, it returned an empty list. How do I make `find_packages` find `something.py` as a package?

```
from setuptools import find_packages

packages = find_packages('c:/dir/A')
print(packages)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'd need to make it a package, it's a module right now. You would do this the same way you made the `A` package: create a directory with the package name, include an `__init__.py` file (in this case, you would rename `something.py` to `__init__.py` under the `something` directory).

`find_packages('c:/dir')` would find `A`, since `A` is a package under `c:/dir`.