# How can I install a python package onto Google Dataflow and import it into my pipeline?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

My folder structure is as follows:

```
Project/
 --Pipeline.py
 --setup.py
 --dist/
  --ResumeParserDependencies-0.1.tar.gz
 --Dependencies/
        --Module1.py
        --Module2.py
        --Module3.py
```

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='ResumeParserDependencies',
  version='0.1',
  description='Dependencies',
  install_requires=[
   'google-cloud-storage==1.11.0',
   'requests==2.19.1',
   'urllib3==1.23'
    ],
  packages = ['Dependencies']
 )
```

I used the setup.py file to create a tar.gz file using 'python setup.py sdist'. The tar file is in the dist folder as ResumeParserDependencies-0.1.tar.gz.  I then specified

```
setup_options.extra_packages = ['./dist/ResumeParserDependencies-0.1.tar.gz'] in my pipeline options.
```

However, once I run my pipeline on Dataflow, I get the error 'No module named ResumeParserDependencies'.  If I use 'pip install ResumeParserDependencies-0.1.tar.gz' locally, the package installs, and I can see it using 'pip freeze'.

What am I missing to load the package into Dataflow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I changed my folder structure and got this to work:

```
Project/
--Pipeline.py
--setup.py
--Module1/
    --__init__.py
--Module2/
    --__init__.py
--Module3/
    --__init__.py
```

The setup.py file now looks like this:
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
setup(name='ResumeParserDependencies',
  version='0.1',
  description='Dependencies',
  install_requires=[
   'google-cloud-storage==1.11.0',
   'urllib3==1.23'
    ],
  packages = find_packages()
 )
```

In my pipeline, I specified:

```
setup_options.setup_file = './setup.py'
```

And I didn't need:

```
setup_options.extra_packages = ['./dist/ResumeParserDependencies-0.1.tar.gz']
```

Reference:
[find_packages doesn't find my Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984118/find-packages-doesnt-find-my-python-file)

Comment: A simpler option is to just use a requirements.txt file, your setup.py is not installing anything custom, it is all things in pypi. `setup_options.requirements_file = './requirements.txt'`.  The dataflow runner does all the downloading and packaging and deploying for you, no need to pre-prepare extra packages unless they are things not published to pypi or they are things like C or Fortran dependencies that need pre-compiling, and if you're doing that make sure it's compiled for the Linux version that GCP uses for its containers.

Comment: Oh wait you do need the find_packages() because your pipeline references `Module1` etc (technically those are packages not modules, because you've got the __init__.py files in there :)  )

Comment: Answer is right and alternatively, you can also run pipeline with command-line option `--setup_file /path/to/setup.py`. See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this issue happens is from a version mismatch of either the SDK or the Worker Dependencies. To solve your issue, [check your Dataflow version](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#how-can-i-tell-what-version-of-the-cloud-dataflow-sdk-is-installedrunning-in-my-environment) and the [Worker Dependencies for the SDK version](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies) to verify if you're running compatible versions.

Comment: I ran `pip install --upgrade apache-beam[gcp]` in my virtualenv and saw I'm running version 2.6.0.  I also went ahead and upgraded setuptools to 40.2.0.  I don't believe there's any issues with the 'install_requires' packages. The issue is with not being able to import/use `Module1`, `Module2` and `Module3`.

Comment: What version are you using for google-cloud-dataflow?