# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tink'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am trying to start a simple ETL process in dataflow to pick up messages from pubsub topic and push it into bigquery. While the messages are being read from pubSub I want to encrypt them using TINK module. But when I import the module I get an error in the dataflow job AS :

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tink'`

```
import json
import apache_beam as beam
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()


def format_message_element(message, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
    import tink
    from tink import aead, cleartext_keyset_handle
    import json
    import time
    import logging
    import io
    import base64
    import os
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    date_time_obj = datetime.utcnow()
    processing_timestamp = date_time_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    try:
        decoded_message = message.data.decode('UTF-8')
        # Id = json.loads(decoded_message).get('id')
    except AttributeError:
        # Id = ''
        decoded_message = ''
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        # Id = ''
        decoded_message = message.data.decode('UTF-8')
    Id = str(message.attributes.get('entityId'))

    # Setting up Cryptography library call
    aead.register()
    keyset_handle = tink.new_keyset_handle(aead.aead_key_templates.AES256_GCM)
    aead_primitive = keyset_handle.primitive(aead.Aead)
    # Encoding the message body into byte for TINK encryption
    encoded_message_body = bytes(decoded_message, 'UTF-8')
    encoded_globalId = bytes(Id, 'UTF-8')
    ciphertext = aead_primitive.encrypt(encoded_message_body, encoded_Id)
    out = io.BytesIO()
    writer = tink.BinaryKeysetWriter(out)
    cleartext_keyset_handle.write(writer, keyset_handle)
    out.seek(0)
    key = base64.b64encode(out.read())
    data = {
        'Id': Id,
        'message_body': ciphertext,
        'message_attributes': str(message.attributes),
        'insert_timestamp': processing_timestamp
    }

    return data

def run():
    o = beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions()
    # Replace this by --stream execution param
    standard_options = o.view_as(beam.options.pipeline_options.StandardOptions)
    standard_options.streaming = True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=o)
query = """
       SELECT 
        subscriptionName, destinationTable
       FROM `myProject.myDataset.myTable`
   """
    query_job = client.query(query) 
    results = query_job.result()

    for row in results:
        subs_name = row.subscriptionName
        destination_table_name = row.destinationTable
        subs_variable = subs_name.split('/')[-1]
        Talent_records1 = (
                p
                | 'read from  pubsub subscription:' + subs_variable >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subs_name,
                                                                                              with_attributes=True)
        )

        Talent_record_format = (Talent_records1
                                | 'Format Talent API' + subs_variable + 'message' >> beam.Map(format_message_element))

        Talent_record_format | 'send Talent API' + subs_variable + 'record to bigquery' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=destination_table_name, write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

 
run()
```

While running the template in the dataflow I get the error :
`format_message_element ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tink' [while running 'Format Talent APITest_DIP_Crypto-submessage-ptransform-57']`

I tried using the import function at outside `format_message_element`; at the top and got following error  `format_message_element NameError: name 'aead' is not defined [while running 'Format Talent APITest_DIP_Crypto-submessage-ptransform-57']`

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
pip list 
pip3 list
```

in your terminal and check if the tink module is present. If not, then install using https://pypi.org/project/tink/

Comment: I have installed tink in my local and test the code,its working as expected. When i deploy on dataflow,that is when I start getting this error. How can I install TINK module for dataflow?

Comment: Is it helpful? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239615/how-can-i-install-a-python-package-onto-google-dataflow-and-import-it-into-my-pi